# css preserve 3d with rotate animation not working anymore on latest browsers

Tags: css, animation, preserve-3d

on older versions of chrome(52),opera,firefox slide rotate animation was working with preserve 3d. Now in the latest versions of all browser this is not happening.
Heres the live link for demo http://codeplay.co.in/expertise
Here you can see the slide rotates flat and when it stops, it transforms with rotateX. On older browsers it used to rotate with transform preserving the 3d animation.

Answer (score 0):

which code is valid for any browser, you can check it below -->

[transform](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)
[preserve](http://caniuse.com/#search=preserve)
edit : it seems not ok for chrome version 52 as site.

Comment: on chrome v52 if i remove property preserve 3d it behaves the same way on latest version. Still cant figure out whats causing the problem